# Any satisfying iterator recursion to replace a for loop of the type $a[i]=b[i]*c[i]$

Tags: c++, loops, vector, indexing, iterator

I am attempting to make my code more readable and avoiding for loops with indices, as iterators are more flexible.

fictive data

```
time        a          b
0           6          7
0.5         2          1.5
1.0         9          3
1.5         0          2
```

now in order to calculate the vector `c` I would normally introduce the for-loop

```
vector<double> c;

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
```

In order to avoid confusion on indices and making the code more readable, however, I would like to use iterators.

My attempt thus far:

```
vector<double> c;

vector<double>::iterator it_a, it_b;

for (it_a = a.begin(); it_a != a.end(); it_a++)
{
    for (it_b = b.begin(); it_b != b.end(); it_b++)
    {
        if (it_b == it_a)
        {
            c.push_back((it_a *)*(it_b *));
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure this is false. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think using iterators here would make the code more readable. If anything it would become a lot longer, which tends to hurt readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want readability use STL algorithms:

```
// Initialise result vector
vector<double> c(a.size()); 

// Iterate through a & b and push the result of the binary func into c
std::transform(a.cbegin(), a.cend(),
               b.cbegin(),
               c.begin(),
               std::multiplies<>{});
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:41,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:41,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:41,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:41,startLineNumber:20),source:%27%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++const+vector%3Cdouble%3E+a+%3D+%7B1,2,3%7D%3B%0A++++const+vector%3Cdouble%3E+b+%3D+a%3B%0A%0A++++//+Initialise+result+vector%0A++++vector%3Cdouble%3E+c(a.size())%3B+%0A%0A++++//+Iterate+through+a+%26+b+and+push+result+of+lambda+into+c%0A++++std::transform(a.cbegin(),+a.cend(),%0A+++++++++++++++++++b.cbegin(),%0A+++++++++++++++++++c.begin(),%0A+++++++++++++++++++std::multiplies%3C%3E%7B%7D)%3B%0A%0A+++++for+(const+auto%26+elem+:+c)%0A++++++++cout+%3C%3C+elem+%3C%3C+%22,+%22%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.39947780678851,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%270%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:gsnapshot,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.600522193211496,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score 1):

i guess the problem is with if(it_b==it_a).i dont understand why they would be equal ever because they are pointing to different data locations. and also you don't need two for loops clearly time complexity in first case in O(n).

```
it_a=a.begin();
it_b=b.begin();    
while(it_a!=a.end()&&it_b!=b.end())
{
   c.push_back((it_a*)*(it_b*));
   it_a++;
   it_b++;
}
```

i think the above code would help . and as mentionted in comments using indices is infact much more readable.